# How to create performance counters that are exposed by jmx and accessed via jconsole?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

How to create performance counters that are exposed by jmx and accessed via jconsole?

Say whenever I instantiate a particular object, I increment a counter.  I want to expose the counter value so I can view the value in jconsole.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few steps:

- Define an MBean interface that exposes your counter.
- Create an implementation of that interface
- Register the implementation with the platform MBean server using `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().registerMBean(...)`
- Access the MBean from jconsole

There are details in the [JMX tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html).